# changing vue version inside a project

Tags: npm, vuejs3

Hi I would like to change a projects version of Vue using npm.
I tried :

```js
npm install vue@latest --save
```

But when I tried :

```js
npm v vue
```

I got the following :

```js
vue@2.6.14 | MIT | deps: none | versions: 362
Reactive, component-oriented view layer for modern web interfaces.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue#readme

keywords: vue

dist
.tarball: https://registry.npmjs.org/vue/-/vue-2.6.14.tgz
.shasum: e51aa5250250d569a3fbad3a8a5a687d6036e235
.integrity: sha512-x2284lgYvjOMj3Za7kqzRcUSxBboHqtgRE2zlos1qWaOye5yUmHn42LB1250NJBLRwEcdrB0JRwyPTEPhfQjiQ==
.unpackedSize: 3.0 MB

maintainers:
- posva <posva13@gmail.com>
- yyx990803 <yyx990803@gmail.com>

dist-tags:
beta: 3.2.0-beta.8
csp: 1.0.28-csp
latest: 2.6.14
next: 3.2.23

published 5 months ago by posva <posva13@gmail.com>
```

Indicating that I still was on Vue 2.6.14.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you check the `@latest` tag on the [versions tab on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue) the latest version is really 2.6.14.

To use a Vue 3, you need to use a `@next` tag instead. But that version is not 100% compatible with 2.x so please check the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#overview) before doing so (also lot of tooling is not compatible as well and because JS projects usually involve "a lot" of tooling, migration might be not that simple)

Comment: Thanks Michal your answer really helped me out!